# visual studio doesnt refresh new copied files in a folder of solution explorer

Tags: c#, file, file-io, solution-explorer

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I wrote code to copy an image file from a source path to a destination path. It works fine. But problem is that the destination path of Visual Studio like \Menu\images doesn't automatically refresh after copying even though the new file is already copied in this destination path. It would only work if I click a refresh button manually. I need an auto-refresh. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 is an IDE, it has nothing to do with your application runtime environment.

Comment: yeah but i google around. there is a way to write IDE in code to refresh it. But i have no idea how to do this...